# Databricks sql query results not consistent

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

The following query is yielding different results every time in databricks and it does not make any sense, do you have any idea? Look at the screenshots for further

```
%sql
select count (*) 
from   (select policy_number, 
               writing_agent_number, 
               agency, 
               agent_part, 
               int(total_parts) total_parts 
        from   (select a.policy_number, 
                       a.writing_agent_number, 
                       a.agency, 
                       sum(a.agent_part) 
                         over ( 
                           partition by a.policy_number) total_parts, 
                       a.agent_part 
                from   ml_raw.agent_splits_dec_12 a) b 
        where  int(total_parts) = 1 
        order  by b.policy_number)
```

[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhTOS.png)
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpJQT.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all information to your question as editable text

Comment: What exactly does `a.agent_part` reflect? It sounds like a part number, but your SUMing it which is odd.

Comment: Can the data in ml_raw.agent_splits_dec_12 be changing?

Comment: Also, +1 about the agent_part: what its data type and what it represents?

Comment: Provide more details regarding the data.

Answer (score 0):

- You are using window function to calculate the total  for each policy number and then filtering the results where the total parts equal to 1.
- One reason could be that the data in the table is changing between runs.
- Another reason could be that the query is not predicting, means that it can produce different results based on the order of processing the data.
- You can also try running the query with different order by clauses to
  see if it affects the results. Additionally, you can check if there
  are any updates or deletes happening on the table while the query is
  running.

For example:

you can run the following query before and after running the original query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM agent_splits_dec_12
```

If the count changes between runs, it means that the data in the table is changing.

You can run the following query multiple times and compare the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   (SELECT policy_number, 
               writing_agent_number, 
               agency, 
               agent_part, 
               int(total_parts) total_parts 
        FROM   (SELECT a.policy_number, 
                       a.writing_agent_number, 
                       a.agency, 
                       sum(a.agent_part) 
                         OVER ( 
                           PARTITION BY a.policy_number) total_parts, 
                       a.agent_part 
                FROM   agent_splits_dec_12 a) b 
        WHERE  int(total_parts) = 1 
        ORDER  BY b.policy_number)
```

To check if there are any updates or deletes happening on the table while the query is running, you can run the following query in a separate window:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM agent_splits_dec_12 WHERE policy_number = 'some_policy_number'
```